# hhvm and cron job hanging for ever

Tags: php, cron, hiphop, hhvm

how to call hhvm in cron jobs ?

In crontab I added given below line

```
*/30 07-22 * * * /usr/bin/hhvm  /var/www/cronjob.php
```

when i do ps aux | grep cron | grep -v grep

```
root       960  0.0  0.0  25804  1140 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 cron

ubuntu    3926  0.0  0.0   4440   624 ?        Ss   15:30   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/hhvm   /var/www/cronjob.php

ubuntu    3928 92.6  1.8 590156 71420 ?        R    15:30   0:43 /usr/bin/hhvm  /var/www/cronjob.php
```

why there were two entries and its hanging for ever ? please help me to understand and fix the issue

Comment: What does the script do?

Comment: loading records from csv file , dataset I am trying has 100K records , aws ec2 with mysql on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: It is quite possible for such a task to run for a long time. Do you have some logging to see if it's making progress or is hung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to data volume it took long time to finish the job, no issues actually